# Missing computed values from table

Tags: stata

I'm struggling with the `esttab` package from the SSC. Doing the following should create a table with the computed values in it to me:

```
sysuse auto
eststo: regress price weight mpg
estadd scalar ratio = _b[weight]/_b[mpg]
testnl _b[weight]/_b[mpg]=0
estadd scalar ratioP = r(p)
esttab, stats(ratio ratioP)
```

In the output, `estadd` clearly says that it added the scalar `ratioP` but when I run `esttab`, there's no value. Any explanation that says this isn't a bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue; the result of `esttab` displays as expected for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from `estout` 2.0.5 to 2.0.9 fixed the issue for me.